# I am able to compile the code but it gives me an error of an sql command. How can I fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was able to write a section of code to delete a customer from the table given the customer email, unfortunately I am running into an error and do not know how to. I am beginner.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER(C_EMAIL IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
  CURSOR CUSTOMERS_CURSOR IS SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_OWNER_ID = C_EMAIL);
  V_ROW CUSTOMERS_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;

  DELETE_COUNT INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
  FOR V_ROW IN CUSTOMERS_CURSOR LOOP
    DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL = V_ROW.CUSTOMER_EMAIL;
    DELETE_CUSTOMER := DELETE_CUSTOMER + 1;
  END LOOP;
  IF DELETE_CUSTOMER = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No customer has this email in our records thus ' ||
    C_EMAIL || ', 0 rows deleted.');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DELETE_CUSTOMER || ' email deleted.');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is ot clear in the error message and what did you try to resolve it? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) [How to create a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to tell you that there's an extra closing parenthesis on line 3, at the end of `customers_cursor` declaration.

Just remove it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER(C_EMAIL IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR CUSTOMERS_CURSOR IS SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_OWNER_ID = C_EMAIL;
```

Also, lines with `delete_customer` variable seemed to be wrong.. maybe you are trying to refer to the `delete_count` variable?

```
delete_count := delete_count + 1;
```

```
IF delete_count = 0 THEN
...
```

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(delete_count || ' email deleted.');
```

---

After fixing stuffs, your final procedure description should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER(C_EMAIL IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
  CURSOR CUSTOMERS_CURSOR IS SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER_OWNER_ID = C_EMAIL;
  V_ROW CUSTOMERS_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;

  DELETE_COUNT INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
  FOR V_ROW IN CUSTOMERS_CURSOR LOOP
    DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL = V_ROW.CUSTOMER_EMAIL;
    DELETE_COUNT := DELETE_COUNT + 1;
  END LOOP;
  IF DELETE_COUNT = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No customer has this email in our records thus ' ||
    C_EMAIL || ', 0 rows deleted.');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DELETE_COUNT || ' email deleted.');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I fixed the errors but resulted in more errors arising. Like                                                    
 2/12      PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'CUSTOMERS_CURSOR' is incomplete or malformed
2/32      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/15      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_OWNER_ID": invalid identifier
4/11      PL/SQL: Item ignored
10/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/53     PLS-00364: loop index variable 'V_ROW' use is invalid
10/53     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "V_ROW"."CUSTOMER_EMAIL": invalid identifier
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: What's your final full code? I appended the corrected code to my answer, and it doesn't generate any error using my test database.